# PHP get everything in a string before underscore

Tags: php, string, substr, strpos

I have this code here:

`$imagePreFix = substr($fileinfo['basename'], strpos($fileinfo['basename'], "_") +1);`

this gets me everything after the underscore, but I am looking to get everything before the underscore, how would I adjust this code to get everything before the underscore?

`$fileinfo['basename']` is equal to 'feature_00'

Thanks

Comment: After the first underscore?  What if you've got multiple underscores?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should simple use:

```
$imagePreFix = substr($fileinfo['basename'], 0, strpos($fileinfo['basename'], "_"));
```

I don't see any reason to use `explode` and create extra array just to get first element.

You can also use (in PHP 5.3+):

```
$imagePreFix = strstr($fileinfo['basename'], '_', true);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are completely sure that there always be at least one underscore, and you are interested in first one:

```
$str = $fileinfo['basename'];

$tmp = explode('_', $str);

$res = $tmp[0];
```

Other way to do this:

```
$str = "this_is_many_underscores_example";

$matches = array();

preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]); //will produce "this"
```

(probably regexp pattern will need adjustments, but for purpose of this example it works just fine).

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use `explode`.

```
$arr = explode('_', $fileinfo['basename']);
echo $arr[0];
```

This will split the string into an array of substrings. The length of the array depends on how many instances of `_` there was. For example

```
"one_two_three"
```

Would be broken into an array

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Here's [some documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an old-school answer in the type of what you proposed you can still do the following:

`$imagePreFix = substr($fileinfo['basename'], 0, strpos($fileinfo['basename'], "_"));`