# Php function that create a new folder with the part of the name of a file

Tags: php, create-directory

I really hope that you will help with this.
Well, I have a folder full of files which has name like this :

AZERRKDKD_00000.csv
AZERKRJFJDD_0000.csv
…

I am looking for a script that can help me to create new folder in another directory and paste this file. Here is the example:

> AZERRKDKD[folder]
>
> AZERRKDKD_00000.csv (file)
>
> AZERKRJFJDD [folder]
>
> AZERKRJFJDD_0000.csv (file)

Moreover, if the folder already exists, I just want the file to be paste in the exact folder:

Can you please help me by writing me a script ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There are two stages to this you can try.  First is to write some code just to list all of the files in a particular folder.  Then with this code, you can split the name and check if the folder exists (if not create it), then move the file into this folder.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for you response, How can I list all the files and split it ?

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php.

Comment: I have my list now :) Do I need to use the mention explode to split it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661423/php-get-everything-in-a-string-before-underscore, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425891/how-do-i-check-if-a-directory-exists-is-dir-file-exists-or-both